# State Management using a global js file without using any library in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the basic Issue if I do state management using a JS file with all the state data and write functions to manipulate data in it. And export all these functions and state to different components based on requirements. 
Finally Adding a dependency to the component that needs to rerender the component based on the state change in the global state JS file.

So what is the cutting difference that makes when introducing the libraries like redux or Mobx etc or why could this be a bad practice when doing a state management?

Comment: Try both and decide for yourself. This is not a Good/Evil world, it is a very grey one

Comment: From what I know excalidraw(which is written in react) doesnt use any external state management. Of course might have to confirm the latest source code. But if they can do it, so can you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could be* bad practice if you end up re-inventing the wheel badly. Libraries like Redux or Mobx are battle tested, maintained by a whole community of developers, and have been successfully used in many projects. You *could* achieve it on your own, but you have to decide wether it's worth it given your circumstances.

Advantages of doing it could be that it's a great learning experience and you gain a better understanding of what state management libraries are actually doing.

Disadvantages could be that you're investing a lot of time to solve a problem that has already been solved many times. And that any new developer joining your project needs to learn *your* specific state management solution and can't build on knowledge of popular and widely used libraries.